# iPad Mini 2: iOS 9.1 iMessage doesn't work after restart.

Tags: messages, ios

I have recently updated my iPad mini 2 to iOS 9.1 and every time I turn it off, or do a hard restart, it prompts me to put in my Apple ID password. After I type it in, it refuses to verify.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is a bug. You should probably report this to Apple Support.

Try to sign out of you Apple ID, then [force restart](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201412) by holding down the Sleep and Home buttons until the screen goes dark, and release. Afterwards sign back in to your Apple ID.

If this fails, try making a [backup](https://www.apple.com/sg/support/iphone/backup/) in iTunes [(download)](http://www.apple.com/sg/itunes/download/) then [restore](https://support.apple.com/en-sg/HT201252) to the latest firmware. This does two things:

1. It "reuploads" all the settings on the iPad Mini 2 such that any weird setting bugs should be fixed.
2. It updates the iPad Mini 2 to the latest iOS firmware possible. Take note that usually there are multiple bug fixes in every new itieration of iOS firmware released.

I do not guarantee this bug will go away, but you should give this a shot.